# If $A, B$ and $C$ are sets, is it true that $(A ∩ B) \triangle C = A ∩ (B \triangle C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm aware to prove this, you have to show all the elements in $(A ∩ B) \triangle C$ are also in $A ∩ (B \triangle C)$ and vice versa but I don't fully understand symmetric difference when it's beyond $A\, \triangle\, B$. How do you manipulate these sets?

Also, not related to this question but how do you negate symmetric difference in set notation?

Any tips?

Comment: This is not true in general since there is a sort of distributive law $A\cap(B\triangle C) = (A\cap B)\triangle (A\cap C)$.

Comment: Any sets $A, B, C$ with $C\not\subseteq A$ give a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true however.

1. An element $x$, on the one hand, is in $(A \cap B) \Delta C$ if [but not only if] $x$ is in $C$ but not in $A$ nor in $B$. So $x$ does not have to be in $A$ to be in $(A \cap B) \Delta C$.
2. However, on the other hand, $x$ must be in $A$ to be in $A \cap (B \Delta C)$.

Concrete example: Let $A=\{1\}=B$ and $C=\{1,2\}$. Then

$$(A \cap B) \Delta C = \Big(\{1\} \cap \{1\}\Big) \Delta \{1,2\} = \{1\} \Delta \{1,2\} = \{2\}$$ whereas ,

$$A \cap \Big(B \Delta C\Big) = \{1\} \cap \Big(\{1\} \Delta \{1,2\}\Big) =\{1\} \cap \{2\},$$
which is empty.

**THIS may be helpful, does it look familiar:**

$$A \cap (B \Delta C) = (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C).$$
So compare  your set on the right $A \cap (B \Delta C)$ $=$ $(A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$ with your set on the left $(A \cap B) \Delta C$.